# Convert NSString UPPERCASE into Capitalized

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have some strings like `NAVJYOT COMPLEX`, `NEAR A ONE SCHOOL`, `SUBHASH CHOWK` , `MEMNAGAR`, `Ahmedabad`, `Gujarat`, `India`.

I want to convert them so the first character is uppercase and remaining are lowercase, e.g: `Navjyot Complex`, `Near A One School`, `Subhash Chowk`, `Memnagar`, `Ahmedabad`, `Gujarat`, `India`. So please help me convert those strings.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24):

nsstring has the following method

```
capitalizedString
```

it returns:

"A string with the first character from each word in the receiver changed to its corresponding uppercase value, and all remaining characters set to their corresponding lowercase values."

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Answer (score 7):

use This one

```
NSString *str1 = @"ron";
NSString *str = [str1 capitalizedString];
```

Comment: btw mate, Ron was already capitalized, I know it doesn't make a difference because the function you suggested works, but for the sake of explaining the example, str1 should be lowercase for better understanding.